# Why does my input focus directive no longer work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, input, angularjs-directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/fXo21LnphHZ3qWnuEMFt?p=preview

I have a directive which is suppose to automatically focus the cursor into the input once it becomes visible.

This use to work, but no longer does after upgrading to Angular 1.4.1

**Markup**

```
<div class="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebar">

  <div class="btn-search"
       ng-hide="showingTagSearchInput"
       ng-click="quickSearchTags()">Search</div>

  <div class="search-tags-input container-fluid" ng-show="showingTagSearchInput">
      <input type="text"
             focus-me="showingTagSearchInput"
             placeholder="search for a tag"
             ng-model="tagSearchInput"
             class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Sidebar Controller**

```
function quickSearchTags() {
    vs.showingTagSearchInput = !vs.showingTagSearchInput;
}
```

**My focusMe directive**

```
.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
            scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
                console.log('value ', value);
                console.log('element ', element);
                if (value === true) { 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        // element[0].focus(); 
                        element[0].onfocus = true; 
                    });
                }
            });
            element.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `element[0].focus();` instead of `element[0].onfocus = true;`

`element[0].focus()` will focus on the first element of your directive template.

**Code**

```
$timeout(function() {
    element[0].focus(); 
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DnGPFripLvn9WOV76RDr?p=preview)

Comment: Ah cool, yeah that does work... but it doesn't work in my actual Angular App :( hmmm marking this, may make another question. Thanks!

Comment: @LeonGaban it should work in any way..did you tried this code in your app & plunkr

Comment: Yes, it works in plunkr, but not my app for some reason :( it use too... but I have a different issue which is more important, will post a new question in a sec

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125880/how-to-modify-this-directive-so-that-once-the-input-is-visible-it-wont-be-hid