# How to modify this directive, so that once the input is visible, it won't be hidden unless the x is clicked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/fXo21LnphHZ3qWnuEMFt?p=preview

Right now, if you click anywhere outside of the input, the focusMe directive `scope.$watch` will trigger and turn `showingTagSearchInput` false.

This needs to only happen when the **close x** button is clicked.

**Markup**

```
<div class="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebar">

  <div class="btn-search"
       ng-hide="showingTagSearchInput"
       ng-click="quickSearchTags()">Search</div>

  <div class="search-tags-input container-fluid" ng-show="showingTagSearchInput">
      <input type="text"
             focus-me="showingTagSearchInput"
             placeholder="search for a tag"
             ng-model="tagSearchInput"
             class="form-control">
      <div>close x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller functions**

```
// search button stuff:
function quickSearchTags() {
    vs.showingTagSearchInput = !vs.showingTagSearchInput;
}

function closeMe() {
    console.log('closeMe clicked');
    vs.showingTagSearchInput = false;
}
```

**The focusMe directive:**

```
.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', '$parse', function($timeout, $parse) {
return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
        scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
            console.log('value ', value);
            console.log('element ', element);
            if (value === true) { 
                $timeout(function() {
                    element[0].focus(); 
                });
            }
        });
        element.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
        })
    }
}
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the blur event from `focusMe` directive which is hidding div on blur.

Instead of that call `ng-click` event that will set `showingTagSearchInput` to false & element will get hidden.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text"
       focus-me="showingTagSearchInput"
       placeholder="search for a tag"
       ng-model="tagSearchInput"
       class="form-control">
<div class="btn-close" ng-click="closeMe()">close x</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.hideInput = function(){
   $scope.showingTagSearchInput = false;
};
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/n6ZjYdIv6QMBEmPYZlKO?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from focus-me directives that, when is not anymore focus, invert your variable.

See updated plunkr for a solution http://plnkr.co/edit/443rVbs2onbx96aq4eaf?p=preview

I have created a new variable, that is initiate here :

```
 function quickSearchTags() {
    vs.showingTagSearchInput = !vs.showingTagSearchInput;
    vs.focusMe = true;
  }
```

And your directive is called like that :

```
<input type="text"
                 focus-me="focusMe"
                 placeholder="search for a tag"
                 ng-model="tagSearchInput"
                 class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thanks! Checking out the plnkr, but loading slow atm

Comment: Hmm, in your example, it still doesn't work how it should... clicking anywhere will hide the input again.

Comment: my bad I didn't fork. I have updated plunkr in my response. sry for inconvenience